# bower install bootstrap issue

Tags: linux, twitter-bootstrap, ubuntu, terminal

I apologize as i am still in the process of learning how to use ubuntu.

First i installed npm, then i installed git.
then i tried to clone a repo from git.
Then i typed the following into terminal "bower install bootstrap".
I already had the source of bootstrap downloaded in a zip file.
I received the following error:-

```
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/bower'
npm ERR! error rolling back  bower@1.3.8 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/bower'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/bower' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/bower'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/bower'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/bower' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /home/haaggis
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/bower
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/bower'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Typing "npm install -g bower" into the terminal produces the above error.

And this stops me from entering "bower install bootstrap"

Answer (score 1):

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

So, what happened when you tried `sudo npm install -g bower` ?